Logitech C270 HD Webcam on Windows 10 Pro: "No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection" Error
I'm using a Logitech C270 HD Webcam on Windows 10 Pro build 16299 in my .NET 2.0 Windows application. When I try to use Camera_NET.CameraControl.SetCamera, I encounter the following error:
No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection.

This application works perfectly on Windows 7, but I face this issue on Windows 10.
What I've Tried:
Updating Drivers:
    I have the latest drivers installed from the Logitech support website.
Installing Codecs:
    Installed K-Lite Codec Pack to ensure all necessary codecs are present.
Re-registering DirectShow Filters:
    Ran the following commands in Command Prompt (as Administrator):

    cmd

    regsvr32 quartz.dll
    regsvr32 qcap.dll

Running in Compatibility Mode:
    Set the application to run in compatibility mode for Windows 7.

Additional Information:
The application is written in .NET 2.0 and uses DirectShow for camera operations.
It works without any issues on Windows 7, so the problem seems specific to Windows 10.
I’ve checked that the application has the necessary permissions to access the camera in Windows 10 settings.

Questions:
What could be causing this error on Windows 10 but not on Windows 7?
Are there any additional codecs or filters that I need to install specifically for Windows 10?
Is there an alternative approach or library that might offer better compatibility with Windows 10?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

There is lack of detail here. Your application is doing something wrong, most likely. I would assume the camera to be working well in other apps.

yes @RomanRyltsov, in the logitech webcam software it is working fine. But the same camera is not working with the dot net application with Camera_Net and DirectShowLib and the same camera is working with the application build with AForge.Net library.
